# Increase width of PositiveIntegerField in Django Admin

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin, width

What is proper way to increase width of input box, in Django Admin, for PositiveIntegerField ?

**UPDATE**

These are my files:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Report(models.Model):
    datum       = models.DateField(unique=True, help_text='Od koji je datuma izvjestaj.')
    osiguranika = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text='Broj osiguranika.')
    /* lot of staf below*/

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.datum)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from hzmo_web.apps.hzmo.models import Report

class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['osiguranika'].widget.attrs['class']  = 'form-text'
```

**css**

```css
.form-text{
    width:750px; 
    height:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py

```
class Num(models.Models):
    number   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
class NumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Num

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(NumForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['number'].widget.attrs['class']  = 'form-text'
```

style.css

```
.form-text{
    width:250px; 
        height:25px;
}
```

admin.py

```
class NumAdmin(AuditAdmin):
    form = NumForm
    list_display         = ('number', )

    class Media:
        css = {
             'all': (/style.css',) 
        }
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. I put forms.py and css in same folder where is my model.py. Should I put it some where else, or there is something more that need to be done ? Also can you put link to some blog post, article or documentation regarding your response. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my post, with content of my files. So if you can take a look that would be great.

Comment: As far as I can see important is to set form = NumForm.  I also have few questions: 1. You used AuditAdmin I used ModelAdmin. What is the difference ?.  I make static directory and put may css there.

Comment: import your NumForm in admin.py

Answer (score 0):

The code below can change **the width of one [PositiveIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) column** with [forms.NumberInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) as shown below:

```py
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {              # Here
            'osiguranika' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width:50ch'
            })
        }
 
@admin.register(Report)
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ReportForm # Here
```

The code below can change **the width of all [PositiveIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) columns** with [forms.NumberInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Report)
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.PositiveIntegerField: {
            'widget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:50ch'})
        },
    }
```

*[My answer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) explains other options to change **the width of columns** in Django Admin.